# GraphQL: creating directives with string comparison

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, relayjs

I'm looking to create a GraphQL query that selectively adds/removes fields based on a variable "type", which is a string:

`query ResultsPage($casetype: String!)`

According to the reference on [Directives](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives), you can use a boolean value to either `@include` or `@skip` certain fields:

```
query Hero($episode: Episode, $withFriends: Boolean!) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends @include(if: $withFriends) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

How could I do something similar with this string value? i.e. only include the `friends` field if `$casetype = "foo"`. Is this possible with GraphQL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to use string comparison. Only way that you can is write custom Directive which can handle on its own.

please check a closed issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/414)